# HTTP 406 - Not Acceptable - Redirecting from .php file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a proprietary CMS, inside the .htaccess file I have a URL going from a .php file to a non php address and I am getting 406 error:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news-and-information/WhyAuditQualityMatters.php$ http://%{http_host}/news-detail/insight-e-news-september-2011-why-audit-quality-matters [L]

RewriteRule ^theme/([^/]*)/(.*)$ themes/$1/public/$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

All lines are part of the CMS other than Line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a `R=302` in this 3rd line, to have `[L,R=302]`. As it seems to be a redirect rule. Or [keep your life simple and happy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html) by not using mod-rewrite for simple things, and write your redirect with [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) and [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) instructions.

```
Redirect temp /news-and-information/WhyAuditQualityMatters.php http://www.example.com/news-detail/insight-e-news-september-2011-why-audit-quality-matters
```

When it will work alter the `temp` keyword and put `permanent` instead.